# Стандартный ввод множеств и их пересечение

Tags: python

> Вводятся два списка целых чисел, каждый из новой строки (в строке
> наборы чисел через пробел). Необходимо выбрать и отобразить на экране
> номера, присутствующие в первом и втором списках. Результат выведите
> на экран в виде строки чисел, записанных через пробел. Задание решить
> с использованием множеств.

Я пытался сделать задания. Но код все равно работает не так как надо.

```py
a=int(input('Ввод числа через пробел'))
b=int(input('Ввод числа через пробел'))
c = sep(a)&sep(b)
for i in a:
    if i in c:
        continue
    for j in b:
        if i == j:
            c.append(i)
            break
 
print(c)
```

Comment: @Алексей Р спасибо большое за пояснение и решение)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала необходимо "нарезать" введенную строку вида "1 2 3 4 5" по пробелам с помощью `.split()`, затем преобразовать каждое сочетание цифр в число `map(int,...)`, затем преобразовать последовательность целых чисел в множество `set()`. После этого произвести операцию пересечения множеств - `intersection()` или `&`. Для вывода через пробел можно использовать преобразование целых чисел в строку также через `map()` и объединение через пробел с помощью `' '.join()`

```
a=set(map(int,input('Ввод числа через пробел: ').split()))
b=set(map(int,input('Ввод числа через пробел: ').split()))
c = a & b
print(' '.join(map(str,c)))
```

```
Ввод числа через пробел: 1 2 3 4 5
Ввод числа через пробел: 1 3 5 7 9
1 3 5
```

В принципе, поскольку в данном случае не предусмотрены арифметические операции над целыми числами, можно опустить преобразования из строки в целые числа и обратно, чем укоротить код. Также, при применении `set(a).intersection(b)` не требуется явное преобразование `b` в `set`. Можно обойтись и без `join()`, распаковав при печати множество с помощью `*` и задав разделитель `sep=' '`:

```
a = input('Ввод числа через пробел: ').split()
b = input('Ввод числа через пробел: ').split()
c = set(a).intersection(b)
print(*c,sep=' ')
```

```
Ввод числа через пробел: 1 2 3 4 5
Ввод числа через пробел: 1 3 5 7 9
1 5 3
```

Comment: `print(*c,sep=' ')` -> `print(*c)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "ну или так" (с) :)